# How to display the response format in xml in wcf?

Tags: wcf

i am getting the output as

```
<id>1</id>
  <name>tt</name>
```

but i need to display the output as

```
<record>   
      <id>1</id>  
      <name>tt</name>

    </record>
<record>
   <id>2</id>
   <name>te</name>
</record>
```

how to acheive this?

Comment: What does this have to do with WCF?  Display of data isn't something relevent to WCF.  Are you asking how to structure a WCF response message such that it matches what you have shwon above?

Comment: yes,how to structure the response message like that i had mentioned above?.

Comment: What does your code look like, and what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To structure your response message as you've shown above, create a data contract class named record.  Then, in your record class, create properties for id and name.  Finally, have your service operation return an array or List of your record class.